# Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger menu not showing

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to make a website with a responsive navbar, but everytime I test the code the hamburger menu simply doesn't appear. I click the icon normally and it changes to it clicked appearence, but nothing shows on the dropdown menu. I used the same exact code on another website I made and it worked just fine, but this one isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NRC Ranking</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+JvJAK8YtahYht1d+K/pv7C5mCVv4VFLw7GMzzRdfAvPEYB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellefair&family=Mate+SC&family=Quintessential&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
      <div class="centered-logo">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img class="twlogo" src="images/twlogo.png" alt="twisted wonderland logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <button class="custom-hamburger navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="custom-hamburger navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center left-links">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">World</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Characters</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center right-links">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tierlist</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </body>
</html>
```

Already tried a lot of solutions shown here on StackOverflow and nothing happened. I've already included Bootstrap's JavaScript file and jQuery script, I don't know what else I can do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want it to only appear when you are scrunching the window to make it taller than it is wide? I think the normal behavior is that you have to scrunch it first. Have you tried scrunching it? (resizing the window to be smaller until is shows up)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make it work when I scrunch it. When scrunching, the button shows up normally, but when I click it, the menu doesn't shows.

Comment: You have `collapse navbar-collapse` classes on your two unordered lists, which are keeping the links from showing. Remove those classes on your two lists and you should be able to see your menus.